# Laravel Middleware - Skip Passport Auth

Tags: php, laravel

We have 2 auth middlewares applied to specific routes, 'external_token' and 'auth:api'. When an external bearer token is presented we inspect it, and if all the values are good we consider the user authorized to access the requested url.

How do we process all other middlewares except passport auth?

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $token = $request->header('Bearer');

    try {

        list($JWTHeader, $JWTPayload) = JWT::verify($token, JWT::TYPE_ID_EXTERNAL);

        $this->user = User::where('external_id', $JWTPayload['external_id'])->first();

        // Can we just set $this->user and process all other middlewares except auth?

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        Log::debug($e);
    }

    $response = $next($request);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Your response would have to send you somewhere that doesn't include the `auth` middleware.

Comment: We still want the user to end up where they are going, but just bypass the auth middleware. So basically there will be 2 redirects? First redirect to route with all but passport, then 2nd route to their requested uri?

Comment: I would assume at least two destinations, in order to satisfy processing all middlewares except auth, you would need a destination between auth. Alternatively, you could process them manually by newing up the respective middlewares and sending the request and closure to the handle method(not sure how this will behave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one thing you could do would be to set the user on the `api` guard, so when the auth middleware runs, it'll find the user you provided. You would have to ensure that your `external_token` middleware runs first.

```
auth()->guard('api')->setUser($this->user);
```

Another option would be to convert your `external_token` middleware into a Laravel auth guard so that you can use the built-in auth functionality. Then, you can protect your route with `auth:api,external_token`, and the auth will pass if any one of the specified guards is successful.

The simplest example would be a [closure request guard](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#closure-request-guards).

In your `AuthServiceProvider::boot()` method:

```
// don't forget your "use" statements for all these classes

public function boot()
{
    // ...

    Auth::viaRequest('external_token_driver', function ($request) {
        $token = $request->header('Bearer');

        try {
            list($JWTHeader, $JWTPayload) = JWT::verify($token, JWT::TYPE_ID_EXTERNAL);

            return User::where('external_id', $JWTPayload['external_id'])->first();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::debug($e);
        }

        return null;
    });
}
```

In your `auth.php` config:

```
'guards' => [
    // web, api, etc...

    'external_token' => [
        'driver' => 'external_token_driver',
    ],
],
```

NB: all untested.

Comment: Ty, I'll give this a go and report back.

Comment: `auth()->guard('api')->setUser($this->user);` worked great, ty.

Comment: Do you know how to specify that `external_token` middleware executes first? I moved the logic into a service provider in another package and now it appears the passport auth is executing first, which won't work with the first solution.

Comment: @MikePurcell In `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel`, there is a `$middlewarePriority` property. It contains an array of middleware classes, and the order of the array defines their execution priority. You need to override this property in your `app\Http\Kernel.php` file, and specify where in the priority list your middleware goes. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware#sorting-middleware).